# Add class to element inserted with TinyMCE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I'm wondering if there is a way to configure TinyMCE (the WYSIWYG HTML editor) to add a class to all elements inserted of a certain type. I'd like Bootstrap's styles to apply, specifically with tables. I'm wondering it there is some sort of hook or something that can add a classname to an element as it is inserted? For example, I'd like to add `class="table table-bordered"` to all table elements that are inserted through the UI. I know there is a way to specify a stylesheet to apply to the content, but I'm not aware of a mechanism to add classnames to the inserted elements.

Answer (score 11):

You should specify it in your editor's init by the help of `extended_valid_elements`. The [tinymce documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements) contains the solution. All you have to do is to complete this setting. At the 'class' attribute you can give your custom class name like this:

```
extended_valid_elements: 'img[class="your-custom-class-name"|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name]'
```

or in your case:

```
extended_valid_elements: 'table[class="table table-bordered"]'
```

for multiple elements:

```
extended_valid_elements: [
    'img[class="your-custom-class-name"|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name]',
    'table[class="table table-bordered"]'
],
```

Comment: There is no need to put quotations around the class name; if you do so, you will have something like ```&quot;``` in your element's class name, so my suggestion is that you can simply do ```'table[class=table table-bordered]'```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Adds a class to all paragraphs in the active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.addClass(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('p'), 'myclass');

// Adds a class to a specific element in the current page
tinyMCE.DOM.addClass('mydiv', 'myclass');
```

API 3x
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.addClass

API 4x
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.addClass

---

Currently I setup a custom stylesheet for the editor and load it via init option. This styles everything in the editor.

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        content_css : "/mycontent.css"
});
```

I store the editor version in my db, then I use [DOMDocument()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to add the front end styling when it needs to be viewed. *Following Php is an example only.*

```
<?php
$html = utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($html));
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
foreach ($tables as $tbl) { 
    $tbl->setAttribute('class', 'table table-striped table-bordered'); 
}
$save = $doc->saveHTML();
$save = utf8_encode($save);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone has a better solution, I might just need to bind an event listener to the `DOMNodeInserted` event that checks to see if a table was inserted and adds the class to it. I'd rather not modify TinyMCE's internals to support this.

Comment: I came here with other problem **setting default text alignment**, and this helped me. Looks like after 5 years there is no better solution to this. But in my case adding just class is not enough - tinyMCE won't save it to DB. You need to add lines like this:
`let iframe_body = $('iframe').contents().find("body"); $(iframe_body).on("DOMNodeInserted", function (event) {   $(event.target).addClass('left');    $(event.target).css({     "text-align": "left"   });
  $(event.target).attr("data-mce-style", "text-align: left"); });`

Comment: @VolmargReiso I am seeing *very* inconsistent results using DOMNodeInserted.  I need to set the `id` of certain elements, but it seems only the first one "sticks" - subsequent elements get initialized with the same id before I even get them, and after I change the id it gets reset back to `""`.  I am adding an event handler which seems to work if I step through the code to add it, but when I don't step through I can't seem to get click events even though my handler is still attached!

Comment: @Michael In my case I'm having panel with bunch of buttons. Each button has separated id. And here on click i call modal and then i initialize tinymce for each modal separately. I'm initializing on `click`, so maybe this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get exactly what you mean but does this help?

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php

EDIT: What about trying the following in the init

extended_valid_elements: "table[class=table table-bordered]"

EDIT EDIT: I think this is also a possible option, should help get rid of the default mce class.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:visual_table_class

Comment: That would allow me to add a custom style that the user could apply to the content, but it doesn't apply it by default. Thanks though!